# How to create and sign a SAML 1.1 assertion in C# using visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, saml

I'm trying to connect to a 3rd party who has WCF based services.
They have a dedicated endpoint to create an auth token, and I've gotten some instructions on how to use it, but I'm stuck.

Here's all the information I have:

- I have the WSDL, so I have generated proxy classes.
- I have the information to fill in the properties for the ws request.
- I have the endpoint address for the service.
- I have a certificate for signing
- The security property needs to be a SAML 1.1 assertion
- The SAML1.1 assertion needs to be signed
- The signed assertion needs to be base64 encoded
- I have the issuer
- I have two attributes that I've been told needs to be in the assertion

So in summary, I have filled in the necessary properties based on the WSDL, but I don't know how to create and sign the SAML1.1 assertion.
The vendor does not have examples on how the assertion should look.

I've tried asking other developers I know, but they don't know how to do this, so I'm kind of desperate.

Comment: This link contains how to implement a custom client SAML token provider, you can refer to it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/saml-token-provider

Comment: @DingPeng I can't see how it explains how to build a SAML from the client side and sign it.